# How to update date and hour, while keeping Minutes and Seconds

Tags: mysql

I have a datetime `0000-00-00 00:00:00` column in my table,

Need to keep the minute and seconds when updating  `____-__-__ __:MM:SS`
but also change the date and hour to current time.

How can I achieve this on MySQL side?

#### Edit (Sample):

Current Date field value: 2016-06-27 15`:13:07`

We Update this table at 2016-07-28 12:31:18

Desired Date field value: 2016-07-28 12`:13:07`

As you can see the updated date still has correct `2016-07-28 12:` but the `:13:07` (minutes and seconds) are Selected from the date before update and replaced by current time's minutes and seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of MySQL [CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_conca) function.
 Your update query would looks something like this,

```
UPDATE table_name
SET
date_column = CONCAT('2016-06-29 15:',MINUTE(date_column),':',SECOND(date_column))
WHERE
column_id = 1
```

> **CONCAT()** returns the string that results from concatenating the given arguments.

So in your case we would update date and hour by adding first argument as `2016-06-29 15:`, and then use the same **minute** and **second** from the same column. And concatenate all the arguments to make the new value as you need.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat